# Floated content of a div, disrupts div (CSS issue)

Tags: css

I have looked for an answer but can't seem to find one. I have a bit of a strange problem, I've never come across it before. Here's a [LINK](http://d311360.u38.hosting.digiweb.ie/)

In my `header`, I have `div id="topHeader"` and within this I have `div class="contentArea"`.

`topHeader` has a `float` and `width` of `100%`, with `background-color`, and `contentArea` has a width of `990px` and `margin: 0 auto;`

Anything that is in the `contentArea` that has a float, disrupts the `contentArea` (eg. I want to apply padding to the top and bottom of `contentArea` but it seems to be only applying to the top and pushing the content down.

Same issue is happening in the footer, `contentArea`, you can see clearly using Firebug,

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `float: left;` from all elements with `width: 100%;`.

Then add `<div class="clear"> </div>` *inside / at the end of* all floating elements.

```
.clear {
 clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I thought I would need the float on for background color? And is adding the `<div class="clear"></div>` bad for markup? I will give them a go, right after my pancakes, it's pancake Tuesday!

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: adding `<div class="clear"> </div>` is 100% valid. And I do not understand what you meant by "would need the float for background color", if I guessed right, no you don't need float for that.

Comment: Hi, sorry for only getting back now, have tried what you said and it seems to be working now (just added it in the header, will add to footer now), maybe you could take a look just to be sure. Thanks for that, and thanks to everyone else, for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

When you float elements the parent container doesn't wrap around the child elements that are floated in this case you need to add a clearfix like this

```
.group:before,
.group:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
.group:after {
    clear: both;
}
.group {

}
```

add this to your css then add a class group to any elements that have floated children, this clearfix has full compatibility across all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you want, try add this: `#topHeader .contentArea {overflow:hidden;}`